# Get all the keys in Array of Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries as Follows:

```
Dictionary<int, int>[] matrix = new Dictionary<int, string>[10];
```

I need all the keys saved in this dictionary which I am using in a `foreach` loop as below:

```
 foreach (int key in matrix.Keys)
  {

  }
```

Obviously, `matrix.Keys` won't work here. So,is there any way to get all the keys of dictionary without looping through the whole array (maybe `Linq` or something)?

Comment: Keep in mind that `SelectMany` is still 'looping through the whole array'. It just does it 'behind the scenes`.

Comment: @mjwills I understand that & ok with that.

Comment: Can you show us some examples of what you plan to do _inside_ the `foreach`? For example, do you plan to use those keys to lookup entries in the dictionaries?

Comment: @mjwills I am storing all the values to a variable one-by-one and doing addition as the value of dictionary represents sort of Count.

Comment: all the values in `<key, value>` represent a count. So i am getting those values using keys and doing the addition of all values.

Comment: @bommelding Sorry. Values are `int` too. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @bommelding I already had done that addition thing as i was using a single dictionary. Later I need array of dictionaries. Hence the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var allKeys = matrix.SelectMany(d => d.Keys);

 foreach (int key in allKeys) ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Use LINQ's `SelectMany`:

```
var keys = matrix.SelectMany(x => x.Keys);
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your result should be a list of keys you could use `SelectMany()`

```
IEnumerable<int> result = matrix.SelectMany(x => x.Keys);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/LgIwr7

Answer (score 1):

To get the sum of all values from all of the dictionaries in the array, I would suggest:

```
var total = matrix.SelectMany(z => z).Sum(z => z.Value);
```

or:

```
var total = matrix.SelectMany(z => z.Values).Sum(z => z);
```

There is no need to get the `Keys` since what you are really interested in are the `Values`.